# Monodevelop 5.x and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, monodevelop, ubuntu-14.04

I compiled Monodevelop(5.7) from Git on my Ubuntu 14.04 and tried to create an ASP.NET MVC. It looks like the project template uses the latest ASP.NET MVC libraries from NuGet which is version 5. The default template looks like it run well.

However, there is an issue with the plug-in. Whenever I try to add controllers or views, I get the

> error /tmp/53c43c27/3ede2dab.0.cs(33,33): Error:
>   `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.GeneratedTextTransformation15b3c7de.Initialize()':
>   cannot change access modifiers when overriding`public' inherited
>   member
>   `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation.Initialize()'

Comment: @th1rdey3 The only solution I have as of now is to create the those files manually.